# Repeat the nth last command in vim

Tags: vim

I've noticed vim can be pretty intuitive, but I'm having trouble finding a way to repeat the second-to-last command (or third-to-last, fourth-to-last, etc.). By typing `.` in normal mode it will repeat the last command. Pressing `3.` will repeat the last command three times.

Let's say I type `oHello<Esc>` then `A, World!<Esc>`. I now get

```
Hello, World!
```

on the screen.
Now, say I want to get

```
Hello, World!
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

without typing Hello. Does vim store the history beyond one command, so I could type something like `3,2.` (i.e. repeat the second-to-last command three times)?

Comment: Remember you can record anything as a macro (`qaoHello<esc>q` then `@a` to repeat `Hello` whenever you want.)  There's also `@@` to repeat the last used macro.

Comment: I'd assume you could also do `3@a` to repeat the macro multiple times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the `.` command in `vim` does not have a history, nor is there any sort of repeat history for normal mode commands that I am aware of.  For the fewest number of keystrokes, I'd recommend `4oHello<Esc>3jA, World<Esc>`.  If you've already done `oHello<Esc>A, World<Esc>`, you could follow that with `uyy<Ctrl-r>3p`.

Answer (score 5):

There's this plugin called RepeatLast.vim which does what you wantbut with a cost: your vim is always in recording macro mode. You can install it with package manager you're using like any other vim packages or you can simply clone and drop it in `~/.vim/plugin` if you're using vim or `~/.config/nvim/plguin` if you're using neovim. To repeat second to last action you should type `2\.` in normal mode and to repeat th to last action you should type `<n>\.` in normal mode.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4381
https://github.com/vim-scripts/RepeatLast.vim

Comment: @Sassan, could you perhaps edit your answer and quickly explain how to install this plugin, and how exactly it can be used to solve the OP's problem?

Comment: @terdon if someone reads my answer and doesn't know how to use a package manager it's really better for him to get curious and go spend the time and learn about package managers in vim. Same for the one who reads it and doesn't know about getting information from docs/README.md for vim plugins.

Comment: That's not the point. An answer that is just a link [isn't considered an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/203101).  Answers should be self-contained and offer all the information necessary to apply the proposed solution. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Actually I agree, this plugin is too hackish to be used by people who don't know how to install it :)